# If am doing a web app, is it okay to use solidity for my back end?

Tags: solidity

The front end is to be implemented in Javascript(React), however with a backend in solidity; am i able to implement smart contracts with variables not ethereum related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you *can* put all sorts of data and logic into the blockchain, but the main question is whether you should.

All write operations cost you (a lot), and most likely you won't benefit enough from the blockchain. 99% of the cases your backend should be on a regular server somewhere.

You should also consider speed issues: using a blockchain as backend is super slow: writing data takes at least some 10 seconds.